# Regex matching CSS var

Tags: regex, regex-group

I've been trying to do some regexp on CSS files to extract var function with --vars only (I need match only var() with --vars (variables with the double hyphen) - see example var(--button-border-width, --test) (1px, 44 - did not match and it is OK)) but I'm having trouble matching closing ')'

For example test string:

```
#ffff var(--button-border-width, 1px, 44, --test) ff var(--button-border-style, solid, 45) var(solid, --button-border-style, ad) #gggg 12345 (...not enclude)
```

Expected match for test string:

```
var(--button-border-width, --test)
var(--button-border-style,)
var(--button-border-style,)
```

And I have regex:

```
(var\(|(--.*?[\,\ \)]))
```

Witch match:

```
var(--button-border-width, --test) - ok
var(--button-border-style,         - need match close ')'
var(--button-border-style,         - need match close ')'
```

I'm assuming that it's necessary to use  Positive Lookbehind (match closing ')' only if 'var(' located before and not just '(' located)

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/07qtp7/1)

Comment: Do you mean like this? `var\([^()]*?(--[^(),]*),[^()]*\)` https://regex101.com/r/3SWhUo/1 Or less specific `var\(([^()]*?--[^()]*)\)` https://regex101.com/r/QYcv0z/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird   I've edited questions - I need match only var() with --vars (variables with the double hyphen) - see var(--button-border-width, --test) (1px, 44 - did not match and it is OK)

Comment: Can you provide more valid and invalid examples?

Comment: This pattern `var\(([^()]*?--[^()]*)\)` will match at least a single occurrence of `--` between parenthesis. Do you want 2 separate matches for `var(--button-border-width, 1px, 44, --test)` and 1 match for `var(--button-border-width, 1px, 44, test)` ? Or should the whole part match, including the parenthesis?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Expected match from test string:

var(--button-border-width, --test)
var(--button-border-style,)
var(--button-border-style,)

Comment: What is the tool or language? You want to get this as a match `var(--button-border-width, --test)` from `var(--button-border-width, 1px, 44, --test)` How many parts with `--` can there be? What if the string is `var(--button-border-width, 1px, 44, --test, abc, --test)`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird 1) How many parts with -- can there be? It looks like a random count. 2) What if the string is var(--button-border-width, 1px, 44, --test, abc, --test)?  -->   var(--button-border-width,   --test,  --test)?  3) I have html without declaration of --vars and I need delete all matched broken var functions (~2k)

Comment: Perhaps if a quantifier in the lookbehind is supported, you can replace all that you don't want `(?<=var\((?=[^()]*--)(?:[^()]*,\s+)?(?!--))[^\s(),]+,?\s*` https://regex101.com/r/0cBNcu/1

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?
`var\(([a-z-0-9,\s]+)\)`

[image: regex]

More information about this regex you can find [here](https://regex101.com/r/QW5wdK/1).

[image: Information]

Comment: I've edited questions - I need match only var() with --vars (variables with the double hyphen) - see var(--button-border-width, --test) (1px, 44 - did not match and it is OK)